# ON DELETE CASCADE deletes extra rows

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE workspace (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid VARCHAR(255),
    name NVARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE userGroup (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    workspaceId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (workspaceId) REFERENCES workspace(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    name NVARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE userWorkspaceMapping (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    workspaceId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (workspaceId) REFERENCES workspace(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    userId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES user(id),
    userGroupId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (userGroupId) REFERENCES userGroup(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And this data for `userWorkspaceMapping`:

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | workspaceId | userId | userGroupId |
+----+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 1  |      1      |    1   |      1      |    <------- I want to delete only this row
| 2  |      2      |    1   |      3      |
| 3  |      3      |    1   |      5      |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

When I delete a `workspace`, all three rows in `userWorkspaceMapping` are deleted, **instead of just the first one**.

```sql
delete from workspace
where id = 1;
```

**Why is everything being deleted in `userWorkspaceMapping`?**

Here's the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tHMZy2rnyvoHH13E7dS99A/1

Comment: You should show `FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES user(id),` table and data... Pretty sure if you go one more time in all of your FOREIGN KEY's there's your answer... Create [mre] using fiddle, for example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 ?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tHMZy2rnyvoHH13E7dS99A/1

I am getting the same outcome, where all 3 rows are deleted, instead of just the one.

Comment: @forpas ... tag a user... I dont see it. But then again, its Saturday evening...

Comment: Goddamnit, It wasn't the `CASCADE` fault, but rather my insertion of data. It works as expected, I have the wrong IDs inserted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `userGroup` table also references `workspace` with an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint. So when you delete a row in workspace, all the rows that reference it in `userGroup` are deleted.

This means groups 1 through 5 are deleted.

```
mysql> delete from workspace where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select * from userGroup;
+----+-------------+------+
| id | workspaceId | name |
+----+-------------+------+
|  6 |           2 | b1   |
|  7 |           2 | b2   |
|  8 |           2 | b3   |
|  9 |           2 | b4   |
| 10 |           2 | b5   |
| 11 |           3 | c1   |
| 12 |           3 | c2   |
| 13 |           3 | c3   |
| 14 |           3 | c4   |
| 15 |           3 | c5   |
+----+-------------+------+
```

Hence all the rows in `userWorkspaceMapping` that reference groups 1 through 5 will be deleted. That accounts for all the rows.

Cascading can and does cascade more than one "step" in the foreign key references.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I figured it out. The problem is not with the cascade, but rather my test data, where I insert the wrong IDs...

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no problem with the `CASCADE`... I am inserting the wrong test IDs here:

```sql
INSERT INTO userWorkspaceMapping (
  userId,
  workspaceId,
  userGroupId
)
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 1),
  (1, 2, 3),  -- <---- should be between 6 and 9
  (1, 3, 5)   -- <---- should be between 10 and 15
 ;
```

They ALL belong to the deleted workspace... The IDs should be proper ones.